# Getting Media from code in repository

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm working in Umbraco 7 and I'm trying to map data to a custom entity i have created. Mapping strings, int ect. is quite simple but can someone tell me how i can map content created from Media picker, Multi Media picker and Content picker?

My simple model:

```
public class Frontpage : Master
{
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public HtmlString Content { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<XXXX> Images { get; set; } <-- What class/type should I place here (IMedia mayby)
    public IEnumerable<XXXX> Links { get; set; }    <-- What class/type should I place here (IContent mayby)
    public IEnumerable<NewsItem> News { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository I have this method:

```
public Frontpage GetFrontPage(IPublishedContent content)
{
    var imageObject = <-- How do I map a image from image picker here
    var imagesObject = <-- How do I map images from multi media picker here
    var linksObject = <-- How do I map a multiple links from content picker here

    var model = new Frontpage {
        Headline = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.GetPropertyValue<string>("headline")) ? content.GetPropertyValue<string>("headline") : content.Name,
        Content = new HtmlString(content.GetPropertyValue<string>("content")),
        Image = <-- And finally what goes here,
        Images = <-- And finally what goes here,
        Links = <-- And finally what goes here,
        News = null
    };

    return model;
}
```

I hope this makes sence to some of you guys/girls ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i was able to call TypedMedia and TypedContent in my repository like this:

```
var helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var image = helper.TypedMedia(content.GetPropertyValue("image"));
var link = helper.TypedContent(content.GetPropertyValue("link"));
```

this way I can get what I want for both media and content picker ;o)